# Applying the <!DOCTYPE html> in xquery file

Tags: jquery, html, xquery, datetimepicker, marklogic

I'm trying to add dateTimePicker of jquery to my UI through xquery code.
without  dateTimePicker functionality is not working correctly.

I'm using below method to apply !DOCTYPE, but browser is unable to render it as html, it is returning as text, please suggest.

```
let $document := <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
    <title>Demo - jquery-simple-datetimepicker</title>

    <!--Requirement jQuery-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Load Script and Stylesheet -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.simple-dtpicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="date.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="jquery.simple-dtpicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!---->


</head>
<body onload ="function()">

    <h3>Append to Input-field</h3>
    <input type="text" name="date" value=""></input>

</body>
</html>

return document { 

      text{ '<!DOCTYPE html>' }, 
      xdmp:quote($document) 

    }
```

Comment: You can't declare a document type after you already loaded the document. At a minimum you need to declare the content-type in the header and it sounds like you haven't done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XQuery does not have a means of producing a DOCTYPE declaration the same way that XSLT does with `xsl:output`, but you can just add it to the result sequence. And as Dave Cassel suggested, you can also use [xdmp:set-response-content-type()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:set-response-content-type) to ensure that the response content-type is text/html:

```
return (
  xdmp:set-response-content-type("text/html"), 
  "<!DOCTYPE html>", 
  document{ $document} 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `xdmp:set-response-content-type("text/html")`.

```
xdmp:set-response-content-type("text/html"),
let $document := ...
return document { ... }
```

That way, you can explicitly set the mime type of the response.